# What does super(ClassName, self) in ClassName(object) do? (Used in django docs)

Tags: python, django

The following code is literally from the [Django documentation about forms in class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/):

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class AjaxableResponseMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin to add AJAX support to a form.
    Must be used with an object-based FormView (e.g. CreateView)
    """
    def render_to_json_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        data = json.dumps(context)
        response_kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        return HttpResponse(data, **response_kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return self.render_to_json_response(form.errors, status=400)
        else:
            return super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            data = {
                'pk': form.instance.pk,
            }
            return self.render_to_json_response(data)
        else:
            return super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_valid(form)

class AuthorCreate(AjaxableResponseMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
```

The code I don't understand is `super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self)`. I know that `super(ChildClass, self)` is used to call methods of the parent class in the code of the child class. But `AjaxableResponseMixin` doesn't have any parents! What does this do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `AuthorCreate`, `AjaxableResponseMixin`'s super class will be `CreateView`:

```
>>> class a(object): pass
... 
>>> class b(object): pass
... 
>>> class c(a,b): pass
... 
>>> c.mro()
[<class '__main__.c'>, <class '__main__.a'>, <class '__main__.b'>, <type 'object'>]
```

`mro()` is "method resolution order", the order which `super` refers to.

Comment: I knew about mro, but I didn't know super could be used like this! Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find a good single point in the docs that ties multiple inheritance, super, and MRO together, unfortunately, but: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance